# trying to understand the use of libraries and when to include them

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, maps, highchartstock

I'm new and I have some questions.
The queries are for each type of graph.

If I wanted to have all the functionalities of each type of graph and load them, how do I do it without having to include the huge list of libraries?

Are there some that include everything?

If I wanted to mix the types of graphs on the same page, for example For example, a normal graph, a stock graph, a map, is it possible?

Are there conflicts between the libraries?

How can I know which ones cause conflict?

I would like to be able to load the smallest number of libraries and have all the functionalities.

thank you.

load a huge list of js libraries. The idea is to have them available to use. I know what they will tell me, you only load what you need, but I explicitly want to know how to load them all without literally listing the gigantic list of js that there is.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there some that include everything?

Highcharts Stock and Highcharts Maps posiadają już w sobie kod źródłowy Highchartsów (Core).

> Are there conflicts between the libraries?

Yes, if you try to import Stock or Maps right after importing Highcharts, you will receive error #16 in the console with a [link](https://assets.highcharts.com/errors/16/) to a page with its explanation because, as I wrote above, both already have the core code.

> How can I know which ones cause conflict?

It is usually unnecessary to import Highcharts if you also import Stock or maps that already have core code in them.

> I would like to be able to load the smallest number of libraries and
> have all the functionalities.

I think in this case, it is best to import Stock with maps as a module that does not have core code and will not generate conflicts:

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

Comment: and if only those 2 js are enough, for example, when using the rest of the js that are available, such as Math3D.min.js, Responsive.min.js, Tooltip.min.js...

Comment: You only need these 2 imports to have all the basic chart types from core, stock and maps. However, if you want to use, for example, exporting, 3D or additional series from highcharts-more, you must import these modules. As for the ones you listed, I don't think they are Highcharts modules.